# What does $! mean / do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

Context:

```
do state1 <- act state
   dispatch $! state1
```

What `$!` does ?

E.g. why it's not just `dispatch state1` here?

Comment: Hello neighbor, have you heard the good word about our lord and savior [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%24%21)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$!` is *strict* application, the difference from `dispatch state1` is that `state1` is guaranteed to be evaluated and not just kept as a lazy thunk.  It's defined as

```
f $! x  = x `seq` f x
```

Forcing evaluation in this way can be important for efficiency issues, such as preventing memory leaks.